# Two divs with 50% width while content inside container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to accomplish the look like it is in the image?

[image]

It is just regular Bootstrap code for columns, but first two columns should be on white `background` inside `.container`, while the other two columns on black `background` and that black `background` is going right all the way to the end.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjbdaB)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p>First column</p>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p>Second column</p>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p>Third column</p>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p>Fourth column</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `linear-gradient` in `body` , giving your `.container` is the parent, and you won't have any wrapper around `.container`

> Sorry that I'm bothering you, but what I meant was to place the image
>   like this
>   [image.prntscr.com/image/78940c8115c943a186500ac24556758b.jpeg](http://image.prntscr.com/image/78940c8115c943a186500ac24556758b.jpeg)

Add another parent `div` (being child of `body`) and add `background-image` to that `div`

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, white 50%, black 50%, black 50%, black 100%);
}
#wrap {
  background: url(//lorempixel.com/200/200) no-repeat  66.6% 0 / 25% auto
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid #f01;
}
[class^="col-"] p {
  color: white;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
      <p>First column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3  col-md-3">
      <p>Second column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
      <p>Third column</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
      <p>Fourth column</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with both image and background-color? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNmKpy

Comment: instead linear-gradient? I can't understand very well your question, in your codepem I see the bg-image + linear-gradient

Comment: Both image and linear-gradient. Background image to show at first, and fill the rest with background-color since image is small

Comment: @IvanTopić sorry for late reply, you can use multiple backgrounds, separating them with a comma `,`, see updated answer

Comment: Sorry that I'm bothering you, but what I meant was to place the image like this http://image.prntscr.com/image/78940c8115c943a186500ac24556758b.jpeg This isn't working as expected background: url(//lorempixel.com/200/200) no-repeat 50% 0, linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, white 50%, black 50%, black 100%);

Comment: see my updated answer, change the values as you like it most

Answer (score 2):

You could use a linear gradient background on an ancestor element.

I've added a media query to handle narrow view. Not sure what you would actually want to do here.

View fullscreen for wide view:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #f01;
}
.col-md-3 {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.bg {
  padding: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 49%, #ffffff 50%, #000000 50%, #000000 100%, #000000 100%);
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .bg {
    padding: 30px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 49%, #ffffff 50%, #000000 50%, #000000 100%, #000000 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>First column</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia recusandae omnis praesentium dolorum soluta aperiam iste eum, neque necessitatibus pariatur. Neque nam modi mollitia in autem molestiae corporis harum placeat quos quaerat, labore ex
        ratione, possimus quod quo soluta libero, quis dolor! Porro similique natus eius et voluptatibus autem dolores.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Second column</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia recusandae omnis praesentium dolorum soluta aperiam iste eum, neque necessitatibus pariatur. Neque nam modi mollitia in autem molestiae corporis harum placeat quos quaerat, labore ex
        ratione, possimus quod quo soluta libero, quis dolor! Porro similique natus eius et voluptatibus autem dolores.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Third column</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia recusandae omnis praesentium dolorum soluta aperiam iste eum, neque necessitatibus pariatur. Neque nam modi mollitia in autem molestiae corporis harum placeat quos quaerat, labore ex
        ratione, possimus quod quo soluta libero, quis dolor! Porro similique natus eius et voluptatibus autem dolores.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Fourth column</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia recusandae omnis praesentium dolorum soluta aperiam iste eum, neque necessitatibus pariatur. Neque nam modi mollitia in autem molestiae corporis harum placeat quos quaerat, labore ex
        ratione, possimus quod quo soluta libero, quis dolor! Porro similique natus eius et voluptatibus autem dolores.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One more level of nesting should take care of it:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p>First column</p>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p>Second column</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p>Third column</p>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p>Fourth column</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

You may need to add an ID to the md-6 class element to manage the background colors.

Comment: this is incorrect, when nesting columns a `.row`must be used http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting